# Laravel 5 Join table query with where clause

Tags: php, forms, laravel

Trying to achieve with Laravel 5.2's eloquent model

I have 2 tables:

1) projects (id, projectName, users_id)

2) todo (id, todoName, ProjectID[id], users_id)

i want to join these table and foreach the table content with

```
->where('users_id','=',Auth()->User()->id)
```

Part of the code

```
$todos = DB::table('to_dos')->join('projects','to_dos.projectID','=','projects.projectName')
                                                            ->where('users_id','=',Auth()->User()->id)
                                                            ->get();
```

the objective is to print toDoName and projectName

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
    {{$todo -> ToDoName}}
    {{$todo -> projectName}}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to create a relation between the tables and eager load the relation.

In your `Todo` model, add the following method:

```
public function project()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}
```

Now, from your controller, you can just call:

```
$todos = Todo::with('project')->where('user_id', Auth::id());
```

This would give you the Todos for the currently logged in user with the corresponding projects.

Now in your view, you can use:

```
@foreach($todos as $todo)
   {{ $todo->name }}
   {{ $todo->project->name }}
@endforeach
```

**Note:** It will be good if you follow some conventions. The table columns shall be as follows:

`users` table -> Model: `User.php`
columns: `id`, `name`....

`projects` table -> Model: `Project.php`
columns: `id`, `name`, `user_id`

`todos` table-> Model: `Todo.php`
columns: `id`, `name`, `project_id`, `user_id`.

Remember, when you follow the convention over configurations, things are much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$todos = DB::table('to_dos as T')
->leftjoin('projects as P','T.projectID','=','P.projectName')
->Where('T.users_id',Auth()->User()->id)
->get();
```

Comment: How is this different than the OP original code? What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @patricus his where condition is not mention which tables users_id.

Comment: @JobinJose how do i combine the column. as the column duplicates

Comment: use group by if duplicates records